# Ruby on Rails - Showing the description instead ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view-helpers

I have the following code in my Show View for a Item model

That is a:

```
has_one :categorie
```

View:

```
<hr>
<label>Categorie:</label> <%= @item.categorie_id %> </br>
<label>Name: </label> <%= @item.nome_ptbr || @item.nome_en %> </br>
<label>Desc: </label> <%= @item.desc %> </br>
<hr>
```

But instead of showing like 'Categorie: 3', I want to show 'Categorie: Band'.I got this code working* but I don't know if there is a better and right way to do it.

```
<hr>
<label>Categorie:</label> <%= Categorie.find_by(id: @item.categorie_id).description %> </br>
<label>Name: </label> <%= @item.nome_ptbr || @item.nome_en %> </br>
<label>Desc: </label> <%= @item.desc %> </br>
<hr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `@item.categorie.descricao` should work if your associations are correct. Is it `categorie` or `categoria` though - your code uses both.

Comment: I'm sorry i translated the code to post here, I guess i forgot that one, anyway, that code worked. My concern is: Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Categorie.find_by(id: @item.categorie_id).description<= this is not the bast way, you should be able to do something like @item.category.description with "item belongs to category"

Comment: you should learn about models and relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
@item.category.try(:description)
```

here description is the column name in your category table

Comment: Yeah, I miss understudy the relation type between the tables, the correct were "belongs_to :category" instead of "has_one :category"!